# vb.net play 2 audio simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, audio

I have a 2 audio sound and I played the 1st sound when the form loads which is:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.christmas, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

And my second audio is when i press the button which is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.crowd_applause, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

but after that button sounds, i want to play the 1st sound again but its not playing anymore after I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to place 2 mediaplayers on the form and load the files into them that you want to play and .Play them simultaneously

```
Dim sound1 As String

Dim sound2 As String

sound1 = "mySound1.wav"

sound2 = "mySound2.wav"

Me.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = sound1

Me.AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.URL = sound2
```

Comment: But thats need a filepath right?? when i transfer my works to another PC the sound will not going to work, am i right?

Comment: You can embed the resource just as you have done with your previous example

Comment: Add those Sound in your project (Add Existing) then change the properties to content then you can get the filepath by using Application.Startup & "mySound1.wave" if your application is not yet installed, just place does wave file into Project--->Debug